# Reversing a string sentence with a chain or list

Tags: python

I tried to transform this sentence, "I am testing", into a list where each character is a value of the list and then return the reverse chain, like this: "gnitset ma I".

But when I try to run the program I met the error, `IndexError:list assignment index out of range.`

```
frase_lista = [""]
i = 0
for letter in "I am testing":
    frase_lista [i] = letter
    i += 1
print(frase_lista**)
```

Comment: Do you just want to reverse the string?

Comment: How about: `"I am testing"[::-1]`

Comment: Yes I would just to reverse the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

```
frase_lista = "I am testing"[::-1]    
print(frase_lista)
```

might be an option.

---

Or if you are reversing each word,

```
frase_lista = "I am testing".split()[::-1]

for i in frase_lista:
    print(i[::-1])
```

#### Output

```
gnitset
ma
I
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both options are useful. Also, I wanted to split each letter no each word and then, save it into a list. For instance, "Hello Emma" creates a list where each value is a letter: 'H' value [0] of the list 'e'  value [1] etc. Thanks for your answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an element `frase_lista[i]` which does not exist yet with i > 0. `frase_lista` has only one element `""` that you add at the beginning. If you want to add more elements you should do the following:

`frase_lista += [letter]`.

Also note that this won't reverse your list. To reverse the list you would need to add all letters starting from the end of the string, not from the beginning.